# trying to find the post "converse to fundamental theorm of calculus"

Tags: discussion

At some point somebody posted a question with the title similar to "converse to fundamental theorm of calculus" , I have tried variation of searches but with no success.  assuming I did not dream it, can somebody help me find it please? thank you

Comment: This one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43801/for-an-integrable-function-f-do-continuity-conditions-on-its-integral-affect-c. You can search in title using "title:converse". See http://math.stackexchange.com/search for more options.

Comment: Why are searches in *.stackexchange.com so hard to do? I know they OR the terms instead of ANDing them. Is there an advanced search page? I usually have to use Google with `site:math.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @lhf : google FTW! http://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+converse+calculus tx, it was the first result. if you can post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: we weight title matches heavily and ironically "converse to fundamental theorem of calculus" *does not map at all to the actual title of the question* which is "For an integrable function f, do continuity conditions on its integral affect continuity of f?" .. in fact unless I am reading this wrong, they have zero words in common

Comment: @Jeff , what happened is another question was posted with the title similar to "converse to fundamental theorem of calculus", but people pointed out that is a duplicate of the post  "For an integrable function f, do continuity conditions on its integral affect continuity of f?" so I think either the original author deleted it or it was closed, The problem is that the titles conceptually describe the same thing in different ways, It has been an artifact of moving from printed media where everything is suppose to have one title but in digital world title should be a list of links instead.

Comment: @Jeff, in other words why is it that there is suppose to be one title, where there are more than one way to decribe the content. Hving list of equivalant titles for the same article is not that crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually have to use Google with `site:math.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: this is on the page http://math.stackexchange.com/search simply type and click "search with google"